# Hashmap generic

Tags: java, hashmap, factory-pattern

I want to create a hashmap where the key is of interface A, and the value is of interface B. Then I want to initialize it with classes that implements A and B. Is it possible to do it with java generics?

That is, I want to have something like

```
hashmap<<? implements A>, <? implements B>> _map;
_map.put(a1, b1);
```

where a1 implements A; and b1 implements B.

The original intent is that I want to create a factory, so that I can look up on  a1 and return an instance of b1.

Answer (score 3):

```
 Map<A, B> map = new HashMap<A, B>();
 map.put(a1, b1);
```

Comment: Although these answers look similar, I'm leaving mine because I think it's best. It's syntactically correct. Working through an object's interface (`Map`) is preferable to having an implementation dependency (on `HashMap`). And it follows Java naming conventions (that does prefix an _ to member variable names).

Comment: Where in Java does it follow a convention to add `_` to the start of fields? I assume you are not talking about local variables. I am not saying its a bad idea, just that if it is a convention, it is very poorly followed. I can find three classes in the core libraries which do this. ;)

Comment: This doesn't work: The commented out two lines don't compile

public class InterfaceHashMap {
    interface A {
        void doA();
    }
    
    interface B {
        void doB();
    }
    
    class A1 implements A {
        public void doA() {
        }
    }
    
    class B1 implements B {
        public void doB() {
        }
    }
    
    HashMap<A,B> map = new HashMap<A,B>();

    a1 = new A1();
    b1 = new B1();
    map.put(a1, b1);

    //map.put(A1, B1);
    //map.put(A1.class, B1.class);
}

Comment: @bench mark `map.put(a1, b1)` does what you said you wanted; `a1` and `b1` are instances of classes that implement the interfaces `A` and `B`, respectively. The code you put in your comment doesn't compile because it's full of syntax errors (`a1` and `b1` aren't declared, you have statements outside of a method, etc.). Do you really want your map to hold instances of `A` and `B`, like your original question asks, or instances of `Class<? extends A>` and `Class<? extends B>`, as your comment implies?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, it would be enough to write:

```
Map<A, B> _map = HashMap<A, B>();
```

Answer (score 0):

this may be what you are looking for:

```
HashMap<A,B> map = new HashMap<A,B>();

map.put(a1,b1);
```